Google Cloud - Quota limit hit while nothing is running in a Project
something weird's going on with a recent project I created on GCP.
Yesterday for some reason the CPU usage was reported spiking to 12 units, which is the maximum configured "CPU (all regions)" value.

This project however only has a single GKE cluster with a pool of n1-standard-2 machines (3x nodes), which was shut down when the CPU spiked.
Since then no more instances have been running and trying to resize the cluster back to three nodes is not working as the log is showing continuous quota limits errors in the form of Insufficient project quota to satisfy request: resource "CPUS_ALL_REGIONS": request requires '6.0' and is short '6.0'. project has a quota of '12.0' with '0.0' available. View and manage quotas at https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?usage=USED&project=<redacted>. .
gcloud cli output
$ gcloud compute instances list
$ Listed 0 items.

GKE cluster status

My question is: how can I find what's consuming my CPUs? No tools, FAAS or clusters are running at all other than the GKE control pane which is managed by Google so it shouldn't (I think) count towards project limits.
I'd argue this seems an issue with the account itself, but am led to believe I'm missing something.

Your question lacks sufficient detail but, from the information provided, you are indeed using 12 CPUs in that (see below) Project. gcloud compute instances list shows the instances for the Project specified in your gcloud config get project which is likely distinct from the Project for which you're showing CPU quota.

Thanks for the comment, what details should I provide?
I definitely checked the output of gcloud config list and the user account and project-id are the correct ones. Also, that's how kubectl authenticates and it's showing the right pods/cluster. That's why I'm confused as well, but thanks for the suggestion.

I've also deleted from the Console the cluster, still showing 12 CPUs. And I managed to delete the cluster and check from the console, excluding any CLI misconfiguration (I do have multiple clusters/accounts available locally).
